# What is minimal user permissions for SWITCH PARTITION command in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need create custom sql server user for specific task - switch partition for one table. What is minimum user permission i need grant for this user?

Comment: [Based on the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) I would assume it's `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: If you don't want to grant `ALTER TABLE` to the user, you could sign the proc with a certificate associated with a user with the needed permissions. That will allow the user to execute the DDL in the proc without direct permissions. See [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) for details of this signing technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimum permission is ALTER on target table.

Detailed in [documentation ALTER TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions)